# start development in Ubuntu

Tags: development, application-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I develop .NET apps on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540/how-do-i-develop-net-apps-on-ubuntu)
>   [What is the best way to develop apps for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8209/what-is-the-best-way-to-develop-apps-for-ubuntu)

I used to develop desktop applications for Windows, I know how to develop using C++, C#, and Java. I would like to start development for Ubuntu, how to get started?

Comment: @UriHerrera The one you mentioned looks like specific to .Net and it doesn't have enough details to start development on a new platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to get started is the new Ubuntu Developer Portal: http://developer.ubuntu.com

You can use a variety of IDEs (some may even be familiar), such as CodeBlocks, Netbeans and Eclipse. It will all boil down to choice, if you ask me. Installing an IDE is pretty easy too: Just open the Software Center and search for the one you want or browse the development category.

If you already know how to code in the languages you mentioned, then the main difference you will find on Ubuntu will be in compilation. Even so, it's easy to adjust, especially when letting the IDE do most of the "dirty work" for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does not have a special framework like Window's .NET or Win32 API. The somewhat special to Linux is the POSIX enviroment, this provides IPC, shared memory, threads and 
such. 
Or did you mean GUI? Gnome is written using GTK+ und KDE using Qt. Using those gives you a native look, if you mean that.

Can you specify a little more what exactly you want to know?

Comment: Are there anykind of IDEs that I can use to start developing? something like VS.Net? An IDE that has or can have GTK+ libraries and POSIX?

Comment: If youre going C/C++ CodeBlocks has an option to set up a GTK+ project, but dont know for sure. I liked CodeLite as well, a nice IDE, worth a try. And there's Eclipse CDT. As for POSIX: there are only headers you #include, once you know what you need. For example there's pthread.h to include and -lptread as a compiler option. Though I dont recommend use those directly, as pthreads are very low-level. Use higher-level libraries like [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). Qt offers a great GUI toolkit as well.