# How to install Visual studio 2012 in Ubuntu

Tags: installation

Please tell me the steps to install the Visual studio 2012 in Ubuntu for developing the .NET Framework program.

Comment: or http://askubuntu.com/questions/540/how-do-i-develop-net-apps-on-ubuntu

Comment: Why?. Developing Windows-only programs in Ubuntu is probably not a wise thing to do...

Comment: Visual Studio is a Windows application and in general it's usually not a good idea to run windows programs in Linux.  If you are developing for Windows you need Windows though you can use a virtual machine for this (e.g Virtualbox). If you are trying to develop for Ubuntu or Linux in general you don't need Visual Studio.  Tell us what you want to do and we may be able to advise suitable software for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio works only on windows. Even if you can run it with wine you won't be able to debug or build you code. If you are .NET devlopper you can program C# with monodevelop.

http://monodevelop.com/